# Implement a ViewPager inside a TabHost

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, swipe, android-fragmentactivity

I'm implementing one application that have a tabhost with several tabs.
I have one tab called schedule, that when i selected this tab i need to see a schedule grid that allow swipping to left and right.
This is possible to execute? One tab with ViewPager and the others tabs with the normal framelayout??
And if it is possible how i can do this?

---

```
       TAB 1| TAB 2 | TAB 3 | TAB 4 | TAB SECHEDULE |
```

---

```
                   TABS 1 2 3 e 4 (WITH NORMAL FRAMELAYOUT)

                   TAB SCHEDULE (WITH VIEW PAGER)
```

It's possible?
Thanks for your attention and help.

Comment: Don't be afraid to post more details about how the tabs are currently implemented.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds doable to me. Both TabHost and ViewPager are ViewGroup. They can be nested. (Even Fragment can be nested now.) As Luksprog said, it would be great if we have more details about your problem so you better go ahead and implement it. If you face any implementation issue, you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

check this blog "Android : Tabs + ViewPager (Swipe-able Tabs, FTW)": - Click [here](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator). You can customize all your tabs.